# Jquery Collapse/Display Divs - Close all other elements then open selected item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

### The Issue

My script should be hiding all elements with class "gallery-collapse" then opening the select content based on the link clicked.

Right now, multiple divs will sometimes display when clicking between items.

### The Ideal

Ideally, it would make sure all other elements are closed, mutually exclusive to the item clicked on. (i.e. clicking on an anchor with "speaker1-expand" would close all elements with class "gallery-collapse" and then toggle the "speaker1-content")

### The Script:

```
<script>
j(".speaker1-content, .speaker2-content, .speaker3-content, .speaker4-content, .speaker5-content, .speaker6-content, .speaker7-content").hide();
j('.speaker1-expand').click(function(){
    j(".gallery-collapse").hide();
    j('.speaker1-content').slideToggle('slow');
});
j('.speaker2-expand').click(function(){
    j(".gallery-collapse").hide();
    j('.speaker2-content').slideToggle('slow');
});
j('.default-expand').click(function(){
    j(".gallery-collapse").hide();
    j('.speaker-default').slideToggle('slow');
});
</script>
```

### The JS Fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/2SCJe/10/

Comment: So all other elements should slide-up when one is clicked on, correct?

Comment: Yes, the other elements should hide first. It's essentially a toggle that hide other divs first and then displays the target one afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably shorten the code to something like:

```
j("[class*='-content']").hide();

j('[class^="speaker"]').click(function(){
    //Find the right class to toggle
    var class = j(this).attr("class").split("-")[0];
    class += "-content"; // <---This is now the correct class to slide down

    //re hide everything
    j("[class*='-content']").hide(); // <--- re-hide everything
    j(".gallery-collapse").hide();

    //Show it
    j("." + class).slideToggle("slow");
});
```

Fiddle demoing the concept: http://jsfiddle.net/Y6mHj/

Comment: This didn't seem to work. Points though for trying to consolidate the code.

Comment: Mind making a fiddle? Could get this up and running for you a lot quicker! :)

Comment: Nevermind. I forgot to replace one of your $ with a j. Your solution works beautifully.

Comment: Haha, great to hear! Good luck on everything else.

Comment: @tymeJV In this same example I want the divs to collapse only upwards and expand only downwards. Any idea how to achieve this?